# Prove that all unhappy/non happy numbers always end up in cyclic sequences of 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

A happy number is a number which eventually reaches 1 when replaced by the sum of the square of each digit. For instance, 13 is a happy number because 1²+3² = 10 and 1²+0² =1
An example of a non happy number ending with cyclic sequences of 4 would be:
**534867**

```
199 -> 163 -> 46 -> 52 -> 29 -> 85 -> 89 -> 145 -> 42 -> 20 -> 4 -> 16 -> 37 -> 58 -> 89 -> 145 -> 42 -> 20 -> 4
```

I checked this with huge prime numbers using the code in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Programming_example)
and it ends in cyclic sequences of 4 with them too. Assuming the conjecture to be true, is there any way to prove that this always hold true other than observation and checking.

Comment: See [this article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1945.11991590)  Not sure where a free version might be found.

Comment: (The non-accepted answer in the proposed duplicate tells you how to prove your conjecture.)